# Log4j2 CronTriggeringPolicy inconsistent behaviour

Tags: java, spring-boot, log4j2

I'm using log4j2 in a spring boot 2.0.5 release java project.

Ran a test logic to log a line every 4 seconds. The log4j2 is configured to rollover every 30 seconds using CronTriggeringPolicy.

The configured CronTriggeringPolicy doesn't rollover the log files consistently.
[Screenshot of log directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhCAa.png)

As seen in the screenshot, debug-103400.log and debug-103700.log files are missing.

This is my configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="logsPath">./logs</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS zzz} [%p] %l: %msg%n"/>
    </Console>
    <RollingFile name="File" 
        filePattern="${logsPath}/debug-%d{HHmmss}.log">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS zzz}\t%p\t%l\t%t\t%msg%n" />
        <Policies>
            <CronTriggeringPolicy schedule="0/30 * * ? * * *"/>
        </Policies>
    </RollingFile>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <Root level="trace">
        <AppenderRef ref="Console" level="debug" />
        <AppenderRef ref="File" level="info" />
    </Root>
</Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: What version of log4j2? Some bugs were fixed in 2.11.2.

Comment: Am using 2.11.1

Comment: Please try 2.11.2